# Это нормальное решение или я что-то упускаю?

Tags: java, libgdx

Есть класс Airplane

```
 public class Airplane extends BasicObject {

    public Airplane(){

        // по центру экрана
        x = MyMainClass.WIDTH/2;
        y = MyMainClass.HEIGHT/2;
        dx = speed = 200;

        // делаю прямоугольник
        rectangle = new Rectangle();
        rectangle.x = x;
        rectangle.y = y;
        rectangle.width = 64;
        rectangle.height = 64;

        // как самолет будет выглядеть
        texture = new Texture("AIRPLANE.png");
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);

        // позиция спрайта соответствует позиции прямоугольника
        sprite.setPosition(rectangle.x, rectangle.y);


public void update(float dt){

// если нажать B, то x сдвинется вправо, прямоугольник движется за x,
// а позиция спрайта становится равной позиции прямоугольника
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.В)) {

            x += dx * dt;
            rectangle.x = x;

            sprite.setPosition(rectangle.x, rectangle.y);
        }
    }
```

Теперь вопрос - не слишком ли я намудрил в `update()`, или это нормально и так и нужно делать? Если удалить из него `sprite.setPosition(rectangle.x, rectangle.y);` или `rectangle.x = x;`, то никакого движения не происходит (только `x` меняется). В общем, нормально или есть решения лучше?

Comment: Если квадрат будет не только перемешаться вправо, а так же и влево, вверх и т.д, то лучше сделать класс, который будет отвечать за ввод с клавиатуры/дисплея

Answer (score 1):

Может лучше какой-нибудь класс менеджер добавить, который будет нажатие отлавливать и посылать сообщение ( или вызывать callback интерфейса ) всем подписавшимся, сообщающее состояние, типа шаблона Publisher-Subscriber.